# Unity game and web browser communication

Tags: web, unity-game-engine, communication, unityscript

According to docs, we can make a call to JS function inside a page, that host a unity game:

```
Application.ExternalCall( "SayHello", "The game says hello!" );
```

Where 'SayHello' is the function name in JS.
But if i want to make a call to function that a method of some JS object?

Will it work?

```
Application.ExternalCall( "JsObject.SayHello", "The game says hello!" );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
var f = function(){ JsObject.SayHello(); };
Application.ExternalCall( "f", "The game says hello!" );
```